# array sorting and manipulation react js javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
0: Array(3)
0: {hotel_id: "90738113", provider_hotel_id: "14549", resort_id: "465", resort_name: "Bugibba", hotel_name: "Relax Inn Hotel", …}
1: {provider: "2,14549", hotel_id: "90738113", offer_id: "43525542|1|11682", offer_refundable: "100", offer_room_type: "Twin/Double room  Promo", …}
2: {provider: "2,14549", hotel_id: "90738113", offer_id: "35700179|3|1016", offer_refundable: "100", offer_room_type: "Twin/Double room  Balcony", …}
length: 3

1: Array(4)
0: {hotel_id: "14879371", provider_hotel_id: "1100", resort_id: "481", resort_name: "St. Julian's", hotel_name: "Burlington Apartments", …}
1: {provider: "2,1100", hotel_id: "14879371", offer_id: "1881|1|40", offer_refundable: "43", offer_room_type: "Studio", …}
2: {provider: "2,1100", hotel_id: "14879371", offer_id: "7841340|4|40", offer_refundable: "43", offer_room_type: "Studio", …}
3: {provider: "2,1100", hotel_id: "14879371", offer_id: "7841336|5|40", offer_refundable: "43", offer_room_type: "Studio", …}
length: 4
```

I need to transform it into a new object where there is

```
hotel:{
  hotel_id: "90738113",
  hotel_name: "Burlington Apartments",

 provider: {
   provider: "2,14549", 
   hotel_id: "90738113",
}
```

any ideas on how i can do this after fetching the array with axios.get()

Comment: Could you give a clear description of the rules of the transformation? We see your before/after but not _why_ the after follows from the before.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a join on `hotel_id`, right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should at least show a minimal effort to solve the problem yourself, so please post the code you have tried so far and where it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the join is already performed.  My solution would be to `slice(1)` the rest of array and stick it in a `provider` field.  That will give an array of hotels where each hotel has an array of providers.

```
let result = data.map(a => ({ ...a[0],
  provider: [...a.slice(1)]
}));
```

Full example (with output to console.log)

```js
let data = [
  [{
      hotel_id: "90738113",
      provider_hotel_id: "14549",
      resort_id: "465",
      resort_name: "Bugibba",
      hotel_name: "Relax Inn Hotel"
    },
    {
      provider: "2,14549",
      hotel_id: "90738113",
      offer_id: "43525542|1|11682",
      offer_refundable: "100",
      offer_room_type: "Twin/Double room  Promo"
    },
    {
      provider: "2,14549",
      hotel_id: "90738113",
      offer_id: "35700179|3|1016",
      offer_refundable: "100",
      offer_room_type: "Twin/Double room  Balcony"
    }
  ],
  [{
      hotel_id: "14879371",
      provider_hotel_id: "1100",
      resort_id: "481",
      resort_name: "St. Julian's",
      hotel_name: "Burlington Apartments"
    },
    {
      provider: "2,1100",
      hotel_id: "14879371",
      offer_id: "1881|1|40",
      offer_refundable: "43",
      offer_room_type: "Studio"
    },
    {
      provider: "2,1100",
      hotel_id: "14879371",
      offer_id: "7841340|4|40",
      offer_refundable: "43",
      offer_room_type: "Studio"
    },
    {
      provider: "2,1100",
      hotel_id: "14879371",
      offer_id: "7841336|5|40",
      offer_refundable: "43",
      offer_room_type: "Studio"
    }
  ]
]

let result = data.map(a => ({ ...a[0],
  provider: [...a.slice(1)]
}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks.... this helped, however, I have another issue with array recursive merge... like the one in PHP.... do you have any ideas...

Comment: @kandre, If you have another issue, you can ask another question.  Or if you need to clarify your question, you can do that.  Either way, you're going to have to let us know what the issue with array recursive merge is.  Go ahead, describe your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe you can try some like this. This is for simulate axios get behaviour

```
const array = [
    [
        { hotel_id: "90738113", provider_hotel_id: "14549", resort_id: "465", resort_name: "Bugibba", hotel_name: "Relax Inn Hotel" },
        { provider: "2,14549", hotel_id: "90738113", offer_id: "43525542|1|11682", offer_refundable: "100", offer_room_type: "Twin/Double room  Promo" },
        { provider: "2,14549", hotel_id: "90738113", offer_id: "35700179|3|1016", offer_refundable: "100", offer_room_type: "Twin/Double room  Balcony" },
    ],
    [
        { hotel_id: "14879371", provider_hotel_id: "1100", resort_id: "481", resort_name: "St. Julian's", hotel_name: "Burlington Apartments" },
        { provider: "2,1100", hotel_id: "14879371", offer_id: "1881|1|40", offer_refundable: "43", offer_room_type: "Studio" },
        { provider: "2,1100", hotel_id: "14879371", offer_id: "7841340|4|40", offer_refundable: "43", offer_room_type: "Studio" },
        { provider: "2,1100", hotel_id: "14879371", offer_id: "7841336|5|40", offer_refundable: "43", offer_room_type: "Studio" },
    ]

]
```

In this array the data is in the format

```
const arrayFormatted = array.map(subArray => {
    const hotelObject = subArray[0];
    const providerObject = subArray[1];

    const {
        hotel_id,
        hotel_name,
    } =  hotelObject;

    const {
        provider,
    } =  providerObject;

    return {
        hotel: {
            hotel_id,
            hotel_name,
            provider:{
                provider,
                hotel_id,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is the format for every element in the array.

```
{
hotel:{
    hotel_id: "90738113",
    hotel_name: "Burlington Apartments",

   provider: {
     provider: "2,14549", 
     hotel_id: "90738113",
  }
}
```